# Как правильно спроектировать базу данных

Tags: база-данных

Есть 2 таблицы Owners и Clients поля в этих двух таблицах в принципе повторяются (может немного отличаются),  владелец и клиент может быть одним и тем же пользователем, поэтому хочу объединить эти таблицы в одну Users и создать связующую таблицу UsersRoles. Это будет правильно или нет?

Comment: Все будет зависеть только от того какой смысл будет у той и другой таблицы! Зачем Вам нужны обе таблицы?

Comment: А что будет в этой связующей таблице, каково ее назначение

Comment: Опечатался UsersRoles

Comment: Понимания нам это не добавило. Опишите задачу полностью что и зачем будет хранится в таблицах!

Comment: В таблице Owners будет храниться информация о владельце заведения, в таблице Clients будет храниться информация о клиентах этого заведения. Я думаю объединить эти таблицы в одну таблицу Users и добавить поле role_id. То-есть у каждого юзера будет своя роль, а так как клиент и владелец может быть одним лицом в таблице Users будет одна запить

Comment: Да, создание таблицы с ролями будет правильным решением!